# My app keeps crashing when opening on the emulator or android phone

Tags: java, android

```
package com.ebonybutler.cexample3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Second.class));

        }
    });
}

}
```

Every time I try to run it, the error

> 'Sorry! the application example3 (processcom.ebonybutler.cexample3)
>   has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.'

I can't figure out what keeps crashing it at launch because all of the java files seem fine or at least aren't any bugs.  Please help!  I've added the information from my logcat below but I'm having trying interpreting what its saying to me.

```
11-02 09:29:10.261: E/AndroidRuntime(276): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-02 09:29:10.261: E/AndroidRuntime(276): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ebonybutler.cexample3/com.ebonybutler.cexample3.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-02 09:29:10.261: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-02 09:29:10.261: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-02 09:29:10.261: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-02 09:29:10.261: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-02 09:29:10.261: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-02 09:29:10.261: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-02 09:29:10.261: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-02 09:29:10.261: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-02 09:29:10.261: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-02 09:29:10.261: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-02 09:29:10.261: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-02 09:29:10.261: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-02 09:29:10.261: E/AndroidRuntime(276): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-02 09:29:10.261: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.ebonybutler.cexample3.Main.onCreate(Main.java:21)
11-02 09:29:10.261: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-02 09:29:10.261: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-02 09:29:10.261: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By my count this is occurring when you set the listener for your button.  Are you sure that this button still has the ID **button1** in your layout's xml file?  This error would occur if that ID now longer existed in your layout

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { ... // <-- probably occurring here
```

**Edit**

so in code terms, this is what I am saying.  I am saying that maybe you used to have a Button in your main.xml file with the id "button1". (see below)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <Button android:id="@+id/button1 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" ...></Button>
```

but perhaps now, you may have changed the id in the layout xml and not changed your code (see 'newid' below)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
        <Button android:id="@+id/newid" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" ...></Button>
```

In this case, **findViewById** would return null, since no such id would exist in your main.xml file anymore.

Comment: Usually right there I get the automatic override.  Is that not right? What should it be instead?  I've never had a problem with that before or in any of my other java files.  Thanks for your help mjmarsh.

Comment: Thanks for your help mjmarsh!  That seemed to help!  Its running again on both the emulator and the phone.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a null pointer problem - at Main.java, line 21.

Comment: if you are unable to tell what is causing it at that line, post the contents of the method and you will probably get help.

Comment: Thanks for your help broschb.  I've gone back and posted the main.java code in my original post above.

Answer (score 0):

You have a NullPointerException in your onCreate method (line 21).
A common mistake there is often to fetch a pointer to a view via findViewById before actually setting a layout. Could that be your issue? If you can't resolve the issue, post the content of your onCreate method (incl. line numbers).

Comment: I'm relatively new to creating apps and using java in general so please bear with me.  Do you know how I could go about fixing this issue. Since you mentioned that line from my Main.java file, I will add the code some how.